# How to set language of months to Polish for a tkcalendar DateEntry?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

Like in the title, how to set language of months to Polish in `tkcalendar`'s `DateEntry`?

```
DateEntry(lbf,width=12,bg="darkblue",fg="white",year=1990,state="readonly",
          date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd",textvariable=two)
```

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't have a `DateEntry` widget, you must be using some third-party library — which on is it? (And tag your question accordingly.) The answer to your question may be in its documentation…

Comment: @martineau I think it is `tkcalendar` and I actually cant find it there, in the documentation

Comment: You might be able to set it using the `locale.setlocale()` function. The command might be `locale.setlocale(LC_ALL,"Polish")` or simply `locale.setlocale(LC_ALL, '')` if Polish is your computer's default language.

Comment: I'm Polish and after excecute code by pyinstaller it translate months to English

Comment: Does it work properly as a regular Python script (i.e. when not processed with pyinstaller)? FWIW, I just found [something](https://pypi.org/project/tkcalendar/) that says "It supports many locale settings." — so the issue may be something to do with pyinstaller.

Comment: when I write in vs code it excecutes code then it shows months in Polish but after I did with pyinstaller it shows month in English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tkcalendar uses [babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/index.html) module to translate the week days and months. The language is set via the "locale" option. I am not sure about the language code for Polish but it should be something like:

```
DateEntry(lbf,width=12,bg="darkblue",fg="white",year=1990,
          locale="pl", state="readonly", date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd",textvariable=two)
```

Comment: I think the correct setting might be `locale="pl_PL"` for Poland.

Comment: @martineau Yes, probably, but babel understands the`locale="pl"` as well, I've tried, and unlike with English I don't think there are several variants of Polish with different conventions for writing the date.

Comment: True, but they might have different month or day names (i.e other things the setting might affect).